# Unity Project Convert in iOS

Tags: iphone, unity-game-engine, objective-c-runtime, kudan

I want to convert my iOS project to Unity. Kudan Framework is used in Unity project. It is displaying two errors in XCode:

> 1. Error verifying license key for bundleID: com.bundleid.app error: (null)
> 2. API key not valid

Answer (score 0):

Are you using either your licensed key (or the provided sample API keys and the correct bundle identifier for each key)

https://wiki.kudan.eu/Development_License_Keys

Comment: All Bundle id given in this link is not valid for device.

Comment: did you use the corresponding API key

Comment: i create my account in kudan framework. where i am getting a key. that key i am using in my application.

Comment: I am using bundle id com.company name.application name.

Comment: try using the bundle ID's as listed for each corresponding app in the wiki

Comment: I follow bundle id as mention in wikipedia ( ex-eu.kudan.ar).  but that bundle ids are not working for creating a provising profile.so i can't run application in my device.

Comment: did you use: 1)  bundle id that goes with the corresponding 2) license key - and if you are on iOS you can just generate a provisioning profile on http://developer.apple.com based on the bundle id, or xcode 7 and higher automatically generates the provisioning